# What is the difference between attributes and points in clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining

I was going through K-means clustering and I noticed that its complexity is O(n * K * I * d),
where n = number of points

```
  K = number of clusters
  I = number of iterations, and
  d = number of attributes.
```

Could anyone please explain me the difference between points and attributes?

Answer (score 1):

It is common that we define samples as some features. For example, we have a dataset of students that each student has these attributes or features: first_name, last_name, grade, degree
in this example, if we have a dataset having information of 20 students, we will have a data of size (20, 4) where 20 is the number of samples(points) and 4 is the number of attributes(features)
I hope this description can help you.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you!